# 3 columns with main content in front page

Tags: theming

I am very new in Drupal and therefore I need your help please.

I would like to have 3 columns in my front page for the main content. Let's say the columns are: NEWS, EVENT and SPOTLIGHT.

When I create an article, I would like to be able to choose in which column I am going to publish the article. I need also to be able to theme the columns... How can I do this?

thank you.

Gilles

Answer (score 3):

[Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module would help you in this regard. In Panels you can place nodes, views blocks, general blocks. All these things can be themed independently.

Panels are themselves nodes and blocks(mini panels).

Comment: thank you but I tried this option and it does not work for me. Another idea maybe...thanks